# how to read python code better?

Tags: python

without explicit (type) declaration I struggle to try to figure out how things work --- are there some good thumbs of rule/tips that you may have for reading python code better? Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Python is arguably the most readable programming language there is; I don't see how you are unable to read it.

Comment: if you don't like dynamic typing python is probably not the right language for you

Comment: We really need some more information on what exactly is hard for you to read. It seems pretty simple to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spite of the first impression that this question gives, I think it is indeed really intelligent because it reveals that you are subconscious of something that should interest any Python's developper but that I find very neglected in general and in explanations in particular, if not misunderstood.

I mean that IMO the base of Python is terrificly quaint and intelligent: it's the data model on which it has been conceived.
In this Python's data model, there are no variables in the sense of "chunks of memory whose contents can change", contrary to other languages, and in the sense that we don't manage this precise kind of variables in Python.

More precisely, all is object in Python, and every object is named and designed with an identifier, but neither the object nor the identifier are 'variables' in the said sense.

That doesn't mean that there are no little boxes, so called variables in other languages, temporarily hosting values that go in and out of them, in the depthes of the implementation.

.

Say an object is designed with the identifier `XYA2`.
Personally I use this appearance of letters to designate any identifier. An identifier is nothing else than a word written in a code. It is what appears in a code.
Note that this appearance of letters is the one used by this stackoverflow.com site to represent a code sample inside text, by clicking on the  button {}. That's easy to remind.

Now, the **object** whose name is `XYA2` is a **real** thing, a **concrete** set of **bits** lying in the **memory** of the **computer** to represent the desired *conceptual value* that it stands for.
This set is defined in C language in which Python is implemented.
Personnaly, I bold the letters when I want to designate an object.
Then the object of name `XYA2` is, for me, refered to by **XYA2**

The identifier is `XYA2`
It is linked to an underlying and inaccessible pointer that points to the object.
This link is done by means of the *symbol table*. You will see very few references or allusions to *symbol table* in general, here on stackoverflow or elsewhere. However it's very important, I think.

The pointer linked to the identifier `XYA2` points to the object **XYA2**
So, `XYA2` is directly linked to the pointer and indirectly linked to the object.
Instead of saying "indirectly linked", we say "assigned".  An object and its identifier are reciprocally assigned one to the other, but the medium of this link is the underlying pointer.

.

And now, something important.
Strictly speaking, a variable is a "chunk of memory whose content can change".
I personally do efforts to never use the word 'variable' in an other sense that this one.
The problem is that, because of the use of the word 'variable' in mathematics,  this word is very often used indiscriminately and thrown in all the wind's directions by many developpers (not all) even when it isn't justified.
Thereby, it is commonly used by nearly everybody to designates the names, aka the identifiers in a code. But this practice is horribly confusing. It should be carefully avoided.

That said, an object in Python is not only an instance of some class, it is above all a concrete set of bits; set which IS NOT, as far as I know, a variable, in the sense of "chunk of memory whose content can change".
Hence my opinion that there aren't variables in Python, since the only entities we can access to and manipulate are identifiers and objects.

However, the processes under the hood in an executed Python program use quantities of pointers that are, as far as I know, real variables in the strict sense of this word.
So, in a sense, it could be said that my affirmation 'There are no variables in Python" is false.
It's a matter of point of view.
As a developer in Python, conceptually speaking, I don't manage variables. When I think to an algorithm, I don't think at the level of the pointers, even if I know they exist and that it's very important to know they exist. Being not at the level of the variables, but at the level of the Python's data model, I don't see why I should accept to believe that there are variables in a Python program. There are variables at the machine low-level, and Python is a very-high-level language.

.

Why did I write all this ?

1)
because the nature of the Python's data model has quantities of consequences that can't be understood if this data model isn't known. Among these consequences, some are interesting because they give incredible possibilities, others are traps (a well known example is: modifying an element in a copied list modifies also the element in the original list). That's why it's of first importance to learn about this data model.

For that, I recommend you to read these parts of the documentation:
3.1 of [objects-values-and-types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)
4.1 of [naming-and-binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

.

2)
To justify my answer to your perplexity: don't struggle about what happens under the hood:
there's a garbage colector, a reference counter, wagons of underlying dictionaries-like entities, a thunderous ballet of values in the secret of the underlying pointers, many verifications made by the interpreter... When something doesn't fit well , warning is given in the form of exception's messages.

## Python has all the machinery under control

The only concern you must have is to think about the algorithm you want to achieve, and for that, knowing the data model is essential.

Welcome in the Python universe

---

## Warning

I don't consider myself as a very skilled Python developper, I'm just an amateur who had a lot of problems before understanding some essential things about Python.
All the above description is my personal views about the data model of Python. If any point is incorrect in this description, I will be happy to learn more about it if the teaching is done with developped argumentation.
But I underline the fact that this vision of things allows me to understand and to answer to a lot of tough problems and to achieve some tricky mechanisms that Python is capable of. So, all can't be false in this above description.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [PEP8 documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) This describes the Python formatting and style.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Duck Typing. One of the purposes of Duck Typing is that you shouldn't be thinking too much about the type of something anyway. What really concerns you is that the the variable can be used the way that you want it.

In Python, you don't need a type declaration because the name you assign is just a pointer to an object, and furthermore it can change at any time.

```
a = None
a = 1+5
a = my_function() # calls my function and assigns the return object to a
a = my_function # Assigns the function itself to a. You could actually pass it as a parameter
a = MyClass() # Runs the __init__() function of the class and assigns the return value to a
a = MyClass # Assigns the class itself to a.
```

This is all valid Python. You could run this sequentially, although changing up the type is frowned upon unless its totally clear as to why.

Comment: "you shouldn't be thinking too much about the type of something anyway. What really concerns you is that the (-censored-) can be used the way that you want it." That's what I wanted to say  in my answer. However, you use this horrid word that befogs all the explanations in Python, the word 'variable', because nobody knows exactly what is designed when someone employs this word: the identifier, the object , a real variable ?

Comment: True. The thing that needs to be clear to anyone new to Python coming from more traditional languages is that everything is an object. I used the term variable because it's more accessible than object, although you're right that it lends itself to ambiguity.

Comment: In reality you want to know that the *object* can be used the way that you want it to, since what actually happens when you assign `a = 1+5` is that object `1` and object `5` are evaluated as ints and a new object `6` is created unless it already exists and attaches the identifier `a` to the object `6`

Comment: " the name you assign is just a pointer to an object, and furthermore it can change at any time." Strictly speaking, a name is not a pointer. A name is just a collections of letters (or more exactly a collection of characters represented by a collections of letters, but that's another story). A name used as identifier is linked to a pointer and assigned to an object. Concerning the identifier ``a`` you use in your code, it doesn't change, it's always ``a``, uh ? The change that ``a`` can support is to be assigned to an other **object**.  What changes is the value in the pointer

Comment: "I used the term variable because it's more accessible than object," And then ? You really think it's a good justification ?? That's as if someone would say : "I know a hammer would be better for this nail, but my toolbox is far in the garage and I have plenty of forks in my kitchen".

Comment: No I don't think that's a valid comparison.

Comment: "changing up the type is frowned upon unless its totally clear as to why" Type is never changed : "An object’s type is also unchangeable." [http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types] The change only consists in the fact that the name ``a`` is successively assigned to different objects, that's all. As you say, if justified, changing the assignation isn't frowned upon. For ex. if a function receives an object on parameter ``Y``, but **Y** is an integer or sometimes a string, it's NECESSARY to do ``Y = str(Y)`` before the following code in the function

Comment: It won't be a valid comparison when you'll have explained what is an "accessible" term.

Comment: I'll do my best to clear things up. The words pointer, object, variable, name, and identifier all have loaded meanings in Python. I'm honestly trying to say the things that you mean, but I'm tripping over the vocabulary and accidentally using terms genericly that have more technical meanings. It would be more helpful to just address where that's happening.

Comment: I don't see what are the generic and technical senses of the words pointer, object, variable, name, and identifier. The problem is the following one: do we consider programming a science ? do we consider that one must express with precision in a science ? has a given words several senses ? does someone makes it clear the sense he gives to a word he employs when the word has several reckoned level of sense ? is someone conscious of the several level of sense of a word when he employs it ? has someone the will to make efforts to express with precision in a scientific field ? etc etc

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. I'm asking if you will correct my vocabulary. If the answer is no, that's fine, I just don't want to talk more about whether I've used words incorrectly. I've had to pick all of this up without any formal education and I'm trying to increase the correctness of my answer. The underlying point is accurate and the vocabulary is not.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the `c++11` then it is similer to auto type.

```
The variable type is decided on the bases of its assignment.
```

Comment: Nah, type inference (such as C++11's `auto`) just makes the static types implicit, whereas Python is dynamically typed. `auto a = 1; a = "foo";` doesn't work, whereas the Python equivalent works fine. Moreover, this wasn't really the question.

Comment: @delnan ya you are right. but i used the similer not equal. ;)

Comment: @delnan Hello. You are not right. Something whose type can't change can't be dynamically typed. "An object’s type is also unchangeable." [http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types]] The objects in Python are statically typed but the data model of Python makes people believe it because the assignation of an identifier can change from an object to an other. But as there is no meaning to say that an identifier has its type changing, the result is that the affirmation of a dynamically typing in Python is itself meaningless.

Comment: in reality i'm a beginner. i know just basics so i ans. what i know . :) but python is dynamic type. http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/dynamic_typing.hawk

Comment: @eyquem You can play Humpty Dumpty ("When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean"), but Python *is* dynamically typed in every sense of the word: There is no static type system, types of whatever you think has types are determined at runtime, not through static analysis, etc. (Also note that I never said names have types.)

Comment: @Arpit In the page you gave link of, the first example is introducted like that "The following example demonstrates how a function can examine its own arguments and do different things depending on their types." In this sentence, it isn't said that this example is to demonstrate the dynamicity of typing in Python. And that's right: this example doesn't show any dynamicity. And surprisingly and inconsistently, the following comment is "This kind of dynamic typing has advantages as well as disadvantages." For me, such a tutorial is bad.

Comment: @delnan No, I don't play Humpty Dumpty who arbitrarily decides which sense he gives to the word 'glory'. Humpty Dumpty is a fool because the important part of the passage in the Lewis Carrol's novel is that he ends to say: ""The question is, which is to be master - that's all.", which means that he thinks he can decide the sense of each word. I don't think so. I think that it's preferable to use every word with the sense that is commonly given to it, and if it has several senses, to add a context to precise which sense is intended.

Comment: @eyquem Great. Now remind me again, which meaning of "dynamic typing" was my statement incompatible with?

Comment: @delnan I just have studied one more time the subject oy typing in programming. It is still far more complex than I was already aware of. It seems that my position seems to be not good relatively to what is "dynamic typing" considered to be, though it is completely logical. I have a problem to understand what is commonly understood by the term "dynamic typing". But I think that the problem is precisely that there is no commonly reckoned sense to this expression. So I have a personal conception, but that is not a justification. I'll explain what **I** mean by "dynamic typing".

Comment: @eyquem I see, but that POV ignores several decades of terminology and a quite useful distinction. Regardless of details of the definition, "static typing" usually does not mean "the type of *something* does not change for some period of time", it means "just by looking at the program, without running it, we can make statements about what kinds of values (a.k.a. types) will be used where when running it".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24287/discussion-between-delnan-and-eyquem)

Comment: @delnan Controversies are mainly due to different points of view. My personal point of view in programming in Python is that I constantly reason at the level of the objects. Not in the sense of "instances of a class", but in the sense of the real and concrete entities that are living in the memory (I believe there are C-structures but I'm not sure). So when I speak and hear about a type , I understand 'type of an object' . Official Python doc says that the type of an object never changes. For me, something that never change is static. So for me, the typing of Python is not dynamic

Comment: @delnan The point is that I may mean everything I want by a word, it is not sufficient to think that everybody must think the same. The problem is however that it's difficult to know what everybody means when speaking of "dynamic typing" since typing is another one of these fuzzy subjects in which few people seem interested to be rigorous. So I may be wrong in my comments if you give to "dynamic typing" a different sense than me

Comment: @eyquem I have a thing or two to say about that, and would be interested in either convincing you or being convinced by you. But this comment section is no place for that. Let's take this to the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24287/discussion-between-delnan-and-eyquem

Comment: @delnan Then , to answer to your question _which meaning of "dynamic typing" was my statement incompatible with?_ , it is necessary that I know what sense you accept for this expresion. - Relatively to my conception (type of an object can't change), the typing of object can't be dynamic, but it's mine and I don't want to be Humpty Dumpty's brother..

Comment: @eyquem Let me try this again. **I will not write another dozen comments** (if only because moderators tend to jump in and shut down such discussions, for good reasons). But I will gladly reply in another medium: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24287/discussion-between-delnan-and-eyquem